# What happens to spells cast from Nightveil Specter's ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I managed to exile a [Cyclonic Rift](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCyclonic%20Rift%5d) from a library with [Nightveil Specter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNightveil%20Specter%5d) and I play the rift, does it go to the owner's graveyard or does it stay in exile?

Comment: It moves to the stack as part of being cast, then to the graveyard as part of resolving (or as part of being countered). Even if the card becomes exiled again after being cast, it's no longer the object exiled by NS, and thus could not be cast again that way.

Answer (score 5):

Casting a spell exiled with Nightveil Specter follows almost all steps mentioned in section '6. Spells, Abilities, and Effects' of the [comprehensive rules](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190125.txt), including

> 608.2k As the final part of an instant or sorcery spell's resolution, the spell is put into its owner's graveyard. As the final part of an ability's resolution, the ability is removed from the stack and ceases to exist.

So, yes, it's put into its owner's graveyard, unless the card itself specifies otherwise (e.g. [Time Reversal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTime%20Reversal%5d) or [Beacon of Immortality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBeacon%20of%20Immortality%5d)).

Comment: I don't think one would be able to keep playing it, even if it went back to exile. The rift would have moved from exile to the stack and back to exile, so regardless it is no longer a "card exiled with Nightveil Specter".

Comment: Yeah, it's a hypothetical situation if the last part would read 'You may play cards exiled with Nightveil Specter; exile them after casting.'

Comment: While @Arthur is correct, it's no longer a card exiled by Nightveil Specter once it leaves exile and goes onto the stack, the point is moot because it doesn't return to exile, unless the spell itself says to exile it, like if it were say [Time Reversal](https://scryfall.com/card/m12/77/time-reversal)

Comment: @Glorfindel a hypothetical based on an invalid premise, like Arthur said, once it leaves exile, to go on stack, that link between nightveil and the card is broken, you couldn't keep casting it "forever and ever" as your hypothetical claims